# 'sect' почему-то заменяется на § (знак параграфа)

Tags: php, html

Код:

```
$str = 'https://vk.com/search?c[age_to]=18&c[city]=8139&c[country]=1&c[name]=1&c[online]=1&c[school]=474359&c[section]=people';
echo '<br>'.$str.'<br>' ;
$str = str_replace(array('https://vk.com/search?',']','c['), '', $str);
echo  '<br>'.$str.'<br>' ;
```

Результат:

> https://vk.com/search?c[age_to]=18&c[city]=8139&c[country]=1&c[name]=1&c[online]=1&c[school]=474359&c[section]=people
>
> age_to=18&city=8139&country=1&name=1&online=1&school=474359§ion=people

Посмотрите последнюю переменную. Почему ее часть пропала и превратилась в '§'? (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мнемоника символа "§" (*знак параграфа*) - &sect; , поэтому сочетание символов в URL дает именно такой результат. Попробуйте победить этим же оружием - вместо символа "&", использовать его мнемонику - &amp;

P.S. Чтоб долго не гадали, [вот вам пример](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i30y-gvhn)